# Button text not showing in SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

[image]

I don't really know what I am doing wrong here. SweetAlert work well, but not showing the button text.

```
swal({
    title: "Are you sure?",
    text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
    icon: "warning",
    buttons: true,
    dangerMode: true,
});
```

Comment: are you using [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/)?

Comment: can you try to specify buttons text like `buttons: ["NO", "YES"]`

Comment: nope. i don't think so. <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script> this is resource i am using

Comment: I have tried it putting ["YES", "NO"], but nothing

Comment: How can one know if he using SweetAlert or SweetAlert2?

Comment: @Transformer you're using [sweetalert](https://sweetalert.js.org/) so the code should be okay, can you share more code? do you have any error in the console?

Comment: I will send my console error. but the error has nothing to do with sweetalert. VM134 jquery.dataTables.js:56 
        
       Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Comment: @Transformer you have to import JQuery in your project, probably JS breakrs before it renders the buttons

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create a clean html page a try it out like this:

```js
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  icon: "warning",
  buttons: true,
  dangerMode: true,
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Probably the issue is with other scripts in your page as your code should work, instead you can try to use Sweetalert2 like this:

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'CONFIRM',
  denyButtonText: `CANCEL`,
}).then((result) => {
  /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    // confirm button pressed
    console.log("confirm")
  } else if (result.isDismissed) {
    // deny button pressed
    console.log("deny")
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.1.9/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

EDIT:

Try to add jquery in your HTML page before other script imports like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Alright thanks. let me try your solution, both of them

Comment: I suggest you use the latest jQuery too

Comment: sweetalert2 does work.

Comment: okay let me take a look at my jquery

Comment: @Transformer i think that your JS is broken, try to share the whole page where you are trying to show the swal and your script imports

Comment: Sweetalert does work separately even without jquery

Comment: How can share the whole page?. Pictures or code

Comment: @Transformer can you share your html page where you're trying to use it? You can use [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for it, paste your code and then press Fork, then share the URL

Comment: ok wait, let me do that now

Comment: How do link my local imports in JSFiddle ?

Comment: @Transformer you can't actually, you can write JS code in JS tab, or host the JS files like in GitHub and then add it in Resources tab, try to simplify you'r code in JSFiddle as much as possible

Comment: Alright. I am on it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238824/discussion-between-nicetomytyuk-and-transformer).

Answer (score 0):

**here is the answer**

```
swal({
                title: "Are you sure?",
                text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
                type: "warning",
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: '#DD6B55',
                confirmButtonText: 'Yes',
                cancelButtonText: "No",
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                closeOnCancel: false
            },
```

**Or**

```
swal({
  text: "Once deleted, you will not be able to recover this imaginary file!",
  buttons: ["Yes", "No"],
});
```

**or**

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

swal("Are you sure you want to do this?", {
  buttons: ["Yes", "No"],
});
```

Comment: works well but no button text

Comment: useing two object confirmButtonText: 'Yes', cancelButtonText: "No",